# A Pentad of Paper Puzzles

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, paper-folding

I feel that paper is an underrepresented mechanic in puzzles, so this puzzle explores the many facets of this subject. It's (almost) all lovingly handmade, so please excuse any errors.

1. Orikami

[image]

2. Transformation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFqvd.jpg

[image]

3. Twists and Flips
   [image]
4. The Main Proof of FACT

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPMGW.jpg

5. Cubed

[image]

META:

[image]

Your final answer should be a single word that describes this puzzle.

(This is my first metapuzzle so constructive criticisms are welcome!)

Hint 1: Still no progress? Perhaps you don't know where to start. Here's ranking of the difficulties of the puzzles from easiest to hardest:

> 1, 4, 3, 2, 5

Comment: Nobody's tried to solve this yet, so here's a communal spreadsheet y'all can use: https://goo.gl/QXh61S

Comment: Are these 5 independent puzzles, or is it a 5-part puzzle with a single solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Partial for 3. Twists and Flips:**

Folding (dashed lines valley, solid lines mountain) gives the following:

> [image: square-twists]

Which seems to read:

> ```
> ROUS
> ITST
> OEND
> THUS
> ```
>
> "Sy Chen One Piece Flipper" refers to <s>[this](http://www.barf.cc/flipper.pdf)</s>(link broken), and I don't know how it relates here. "Square twists" refer to [this origami pattern](http://www.cutoutfoldup.com/1604-square-twist.php) which does occur in this folding pattern.

Comment: I hid the image for you and hid/formatted your block using <pre> and <br>.  You could also use <code>, which has slightly different results (you can preview it while editing to see which you prefer).  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: :D Thanks for trying out my puzzle! An actual paper model might be useful for this one. Some of the letters are kinda wonky because of the constraints so I'll just say that the B should be an R.